# 1045 - Access denied for user when importing csv file

Tags: mysql

Hello I am tryign this script in godaddy myphpadmin:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/public_html/data/up.csv'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '/n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

and it gives this error

#1045 - Access denied for user '88888'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I checked permisions on file and thye are all given - maybe this is because i am usign the shared hosting plan on godaddy? where I can adjust access priviliges for my cpanel account

Comment: This error message says you could not access mysql, not the file. You need the correct username and password. Having said that, shared database plans rarely give you access to load data statement.

Comment: thanks - I checked the mysql data and it shows the user name different from the one I use to access the phpadmin....shoudl I access the databse using this id?